# Subprocess won't capture powershell output

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, output

I have a very simple script that prints out a powershell output using Python's `subprocess` library:

```
import subprocess

out = subprocess.run(
    ['powershell', '-command', '"Get-MpComputerStatus"'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    shell = True
    )

print(out.stdout)
```

The output I get printed out is `b'Get-MpComputerStatus\r\n'` which is wrong.

The expected output is list of various computer stats (see for yourself by running `powershell -command "Get-MpComputerStatus"`).

Also I tried `os.system('powershell -command "Get-MpComputerStatus"')` which works, but I cannot capture the output using `os.system`.

Comment: Did you set the `capture_output` flag to `True`? It's `False` by default and incompatible with setting the `stdout`.

Comment: I tried per your suggestion to set `capture_output` to `True` (had to remove the `stdout` due to `ValueError`) and still gives me the _bad_ output (`b'Get-MpComputerStatus\r\n'`).

Comment: Yes, I said that these flags are incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Get-MpComputerStatus` shouldn't be enclosed in quotes.

```
import subprocess

out = subprocess.run(
    ['powershell', '-command', 'Get-MpComputerStatus'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE
    )

print(out.stdout)
```

**UPD:** It turned out, that flags `capture_output` and `text` aren't necessary. The PowerShell command captured in quotes is the only problem. I aslo agree with @tripleee on `shell`. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Ok, with your answer, I manage to determine the issue. It was the braces. Keeping my flags (`stdout = subprocess.PIPE,`) or using yours both work. The core issue were the braces. (will mark answered in 5 min)

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner Glad to hear, I'll edit my answer correspondingly.

Comment: `shell=True` is also wrong here. It's probably harmless, but useless and potentially confusing.